# How to construct polynomial functions, without symbolic toolbox

Tags: matlab

Here's my approach:

Given an array of the coeficients `C=[cn, cn-1, ...,c0]` my function would be the following

```
g=@(x) x.^(n:-1:0)*transpose(C)
```

But when trying to evaluate integral(g,min,max), it doesn't allow. It's probably due to how integral function is defined, but is there a way to construct this polynomial, so I can integrate them? I'm aware of the polyint function, but I'll need this function to evaluate the integral of g(x)*f(x), with f(x) being some "generic" function.

Comment: `g = @(x) polyval( C, x )`? If not, it looks like you'd want `.*` instead of `*` with your own formulation, and to wrap everything after `(x)` in a `sum()` - although I guess you might be trying to do that implicitly with matrix multiplication. `it doesn't allow` isn't an error message we can guess at though, please [edit] your question to include a [mcve] and the full error

Comment: The problem is clear from the [documentation of `integral`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/integral.html?lang=en#btbbkta-3): _For scalar-valued problems, the function `y = fun(x)` must accept a vector argument, `x`, and return a vector result, `y`. This generally means that `fun` must use array operators instead of matrix operators. For example, use `.*` (`times`) rather than `*` (`mtimes`)_